ODBC Driver continuing to fail credential authentication
I am currently using an ODBC driver to pull in several tables from an IBM AS400 system. I have been able to connect the tables, build reports refresh data etc. on a fairly consistent basis, however I have  been receiving a message stating that the ODBC driver could not authenticate the credentials I've provided when I either 1) attempt to add a new data source or 2) attempt to refresh the data(see screenshot). There are cases where I can do these things without any issue and other times where the message will prompt.
When I select "Use alternate credentials" and I manually put in my UN and Password, the message remains. Note: My windows and AS400 Username and Password match.
I've tried restarting my laptop, closing & re-opening Power BI but this doesn't solve the problem. The only thing that helps is well... patience... waiting for the error message to go away on it's own.

what do you mean, adding a new data source?   Does that mean connecting to another system? To troubleshoot, I would use excel as the ODBC client.  Just to isolate that the ODBC driver is not the problem.
